# Creating a HashMap with ArrayLists

Tags: java

I'm making a Project manager program (a very simple one). Basically there are CoWorkers and their tasks. Now, I made the following structure: I'm using the `HashMap` keys as the name of the CoWorkers and the value is always the CoWorkers `ArryList` which contains his or her jobs of course.

My issue is I can create this structure but when I try to add a task one of the ArrayLists I always getting `null` as a return value.

Here are my code snippets:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> jobs = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

public void createJobs(){
    nameReader();
    for(String name:names){
        File f = new File(name+"_job.txt");
        if(f.exists()){
            jobs.put(name, jobReader(name));
        }
    }
    Set set = jobs.entrySet(); 
    Iterator i = set.iterator(); 
    while(i.hasNext()) { 
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); 
        System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": "); 
        System.out.println(me.getValue()); 
    } 
}
```

After this method on the console i see the following result:

> George: [do the laundry]

So i assume that i did everything all right.

But then:

```
public void addJob(String name, String job){
    try{
        List<String> itemsList = jobs.get(name);
    itemsList.add(job);
    }catch(Exception ex){
         System.err.println(ex.getMessage() + jobs.get(name) +name);
    }
}
```

and I'm calling this method:

```
addjob("George","Clean up your room!");
```

the result on the console will be:

> nullnullGeorge

**UPDATE**

```
public ArrayList jobReader(String name){
    ArrayList<String> tasks = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(name+"_job.txt"));
        while (s.hasNext()){
            tasks.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
    return tasks;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is my hole code:

```
public class CoWorkers {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> jobs = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void createJobs(){
        nameReader();
        for(String name:names){
            File f = new File(name+"_job.txt");
            if(f.exists()){
                jobs.put(name, jobReader(name));
            }
        }
        Set set = jobs.entrySet(); 
        Iterator i = set.iterator(); 
        while(i.hasNext()) { 
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); 
            System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": "); 
            System.out.println(me.getValue()); 
        } 
    }

    public void addName(String name){
        try{
            String filename= "Names.txt";
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true); 
            fw.write(name+"\n");
            fw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void addJob(String name, String job){
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        try{
            List<String> itemsList = jobs.get(name);
            itemsList.add(job);
        }catch(Exception ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList jobReader(String name){
        ArrayList<String> tasks = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(name+"_job.txt"));
            while (s.hasNext()){
                tasks.add(s.next());
            }
            s.close();
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
        return tasks;
    }

    public void nameReader(){
        names.clear();
        try{
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Names.txt"));
            while (s.hasNext()){
                names.add(s.next());
            }
            s.close();
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CoWorkers project = new CoWorkers();
        project.createJobs();
        project.addJob("George","Do the laundry");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are your methods being called from?

Comment: can you print the contents of jobs in the addJob method and verify that the contents still are there when you are adding a new job?

Comment: Also, instead of printing ex.getMessage(), call ex.printStackTrace(). It's often pretty helpful

Comment: Thank you for your comments i tried ex.printStackTrace() and this is what i get: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at CoWorkers.addJob(CoWorkers.java:46)
 at CoWorkers.main(CoWorkers.java:101)`

Comment: Is addJob() called after createJobs() in the same execution?

Comment: And i would love to check my arrayLists but that is the main issue i cannot reach them :)

Comment: Show us the method that is calling these methods, please

Comment: If this is the first time you're adding a job for key _George_, you will need to create a new `ArrayList` before attempting to add the _job_ value to it in `itemsList.add(job);`

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {
  CoWorkers project = new CoWorkers();
  project.createJobs();
  project.addJob("George","Do the laundry");
 }`

Comment: Why don't you print the whole map instead to check?

Comment: Alex you are right but lets just assume now that this isn't the first time

Comment: Kal i already printing the HashMap in the createJobs method

Comment: What do you want the behavior of `addJob` to be if you haven't added the person yet?

Comment: Nope addJob(String name) means that i receive the name of the CoWorker and i append a task to his array list

Comment: Does George_job.txt exist?

Comment: Yes i created it but not with the program just my self for testing this class

Comment: I tried this, and I got that error when George_job.txt didn't exist. Are you still getting the error?

Comment: Of course you get this error for this class you have to create the txt file first yourself. That part of the program hasn't been written yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I created my own little test class and proved that your code works.

I don't think you're showing us everything here.

I think somewhere you have two definitions of the variable "jobs", one is hiding the other.

------updated------

OK, so I run your code with hard-coded names and jobs and it works just fine. My suggestion: try doing the same.

```
       String names[] = {"George", "Bill"};
        for(String name:names){          
             jobs.put(name, jobReader(name));              
        }

       public ArrayList jobReader(String name){
        ArrayList<String> tasks = new ArrayList<String>();
                tasks.add("Tidy");
            return tasks;
    }
```

I suspect that what you read from the File is not matching "George", even though we can't as yet see why. Once we have confidence in the list handling then we can think about the data.

Comment: Thank you i'm trying this now.

Comment: So the issue is with the files then? How should i clean the read lines?

Comment: In a debugger compare what you are reading with what you expect. Do you have a line termination character perhaps? Tell us what you get and we can figure it out.

Comment: A whitespace after the name... Thank you for your help really appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking upon the code ex.getMessage() + jobs.get(name) +name , u must be getting null pointer exception as your console prints nullnullGeorge
It means  List itemsList = jobs.get(name);//This is null and hence is the list .
Adding null to List will give u null pointer Exception.That means while adding George in Map , didn't happen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I assume you are right but where is the issue then?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a good idea to check if your map contains a key yet if you're going to be manipulating the value. For example:

```
public void addJob(String name, String job){

    if (!jobs.containsKey(name)) {
        jobs.put(name, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    List<String> itemsList = jobs.get(name);
    itemsList.add(job);
}
```

One other issue you have is that you fail silently when you can't find the file with someone's jobs. Consider adding this into `createJobs()`

```
    for(String name:names){
        File f = new File(name+"_job.txt");
        if(f.exists()){
            jobs.put(name, jobReader(name));
        } else { // This is new
            jobs.put(name, new ArrayList<String>());
        }
    }
```